# What is the Best Practice to fetch data using Firestore Reference Type data-field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a doc structure

```
oil:{
    oilStock_Reference :  oil-stock/example123,
    Qty :  2,
    price: 1200,
    }
```

Whenever I fetch documents from the `oil` collection, I get this data defined above but then I have to make another fetch request to get the `oilStock_Reference` data from another collection.

```
// Updated Data after second get request 
oil:{
    oilStock_Reference :  {oilName:'Castrol', purchase:2000}, //reassigned requested data on same property
    Qty :  2,
    price: 1200,
    }
```

The thing I want you to understand is that I have to hit 2 **get** requests for fetching one complete document.

But this technique is causing me more loading time

*Is there any way to get this data from reducing two requests to one request?*

**OR**

*Is there any way to get this data in a better and fast way?*

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get this data from reducing two requests to one request?

No, not while you have in two different documents.  The only way to improve this is to put all data in one document.

Loading two documents is normal.  I suggest benchmarking your code before assuming that load times are bad.  All requests and responses are pipelined over a single connection, so there is no additional overhead for establishing a connection for any requests after the first one after the page loads.